# How do I implement RS512 or higher security algorithm in PHP REST website?

Tags: php, rest, encryption

I am a completely new person to cryptography. I have tried HS256, RS256 but they got cracked. Where can I find RS512 or higher security algorithm tutorial for PHP REST?

I tried with documentation of 
https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt there is documentation for RS256. but token generated using that one gets cracked here https://base64decode.org. I have tried with longer length keys as well. 
The I tried with https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework There is description for components but hardly I could understand about how to use it.

```
$token = array(
   "iss" => $iss,
   "aud" => $aud,
   "iat" => $iat,
   "nbf" => $nbf,
   "exp" => $exp,
   "data" => array(
       "egfield1" => $user->egfield1,
       "egfield2" => $user->egfield2,
       "egfield3" => $user->egfield3,
       "egfield4" => $user->egfield4
   )
);
    //example private
    $privateKey = <<<EOD
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIICXAIBAAKBgQC8kGa1pSjbSYZVebtTRBLxBz5H4i2p/llLCrEeQhta5kaQu/Rn
    vuER4W8oDH3+3iuIYW4VQAzyqFpwuzjkDI+17t5t0tyazyZ8JXw+KgXTxldMPEL9
    5+qVhgXvwtihXC1c5oGbRlEDvDF6Sa53rcFVsYJ4ehde/zUxo6UvS7UrBQIDAQAB
    AoGAb/MXV46XxCFRxNuB8LyAtmLDgi/xRnTAlMHjSACddwkyKem8//8eZtw9fzxz
    bWZ/1/doQOuHBGYZU8aDzzj59FZ78dyzNFoF91hbvZKkg+6wGyd/LrGVEB+Xre0J
    Nil0GReM2AHDNZUYRv+HYJPIOrB0CRczLQsgFJ8K6aAD6F0CQQDzbpjYdx10qgK1
    cP59UHiHjPZYC0loEsk7s+hUmT3QHerAQJMZWC11Qrn2N+ybwwNblDKv+s5qgMQ5
    5tNoQ9IfAkEAxkyffU6ythpg/H0Ixe1I2rd0GbF05biIzO/i77Det3n4YsJVlDck
    ZkcvY3SK2iRIL4c9yY6hlIhs+K9wXTtGWwJBAO9Dskl48mO7woPR9uD22jDpNSwe
    k90OMepTjzSvlhjbfuPN1IdhqvSJTDychRwn1kIJ7LQZgQ8fVz9OCFZ/6qMCQGOb
    qaGwHmUK6xzpUbbacnYrIM6nLSkXgOAwv7XXCojvY614ILTK3iXiLBOxPu5Eu13k
    eUz9sHyD6vkgZzjtxXECQAkp4Xerf5TGfQXGXhxIX52yH+N2LtujCdkQZjXAsGdm
    B2zNzvrlgRmgBrklMTrMYgm1NPcW+bRLGcwgW2PTvNM=

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $privateKey, 'RS256');

//example token RS256 generated
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJkZGQuaW4iLCJhdWQiOiJubm4uY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ4NTA0MDQzLCJuYmYiOjE1NDg1MDQwNDMsImV4cCI6MTU0ODU5MDQ0MywiZGF0YSI6eyJibGFoIGJsYWggYmxhaCI6ImJsYWggYmxhaCBibGFoIn19.Z9PdtP0ziezMxEpVBvgdsLBKndcy1fHDe5I2ypxvd2BEXSXxifLw2zJ3o3bcVZ5MogBaBbZyJOIxHA5M2XnLah90e48wVo5rXlG13edPCnPy4yt6onSfNO86Jbimr-JmQqDiN2oCeFBVCmqWu0wGxHZsyiOfp1dkBuyCJNz6mi0
```

issue is that it does get decoded on that site without any key

I am not able to understand am I doing wrong here or the algorithms are crackable or something. Please guide. Thank you

Comment: If your RS256 signature got 'cracked' the problem is not that you need a stronger signature. If being 'cracked' is your main problem, the issue is somewhere else. What do you mean by cracked?

Comment: I went to that website base64decode ( mentioned above ) pasted my JSON token in there, and it reveals the contents of token like expiry, issue time, some token payload. You can try and paste it over there too. I do not want that to happen.

Comment: RS256, RS512 and HS256 are used for signing JSON objects, not encryption. I don't believe the library you linked supports JWE (JSON Web Encryption)

Comment: I think you've completely missed the point of JWTs...  You technically can encrypt the entire token, but RS512 isn't what you want to use for that.  Tell us what you're using JWTs for?

Comment: I am developing a php rest project (first one actually) using it for user authentication. Now here, I am not implementing session, the token is my only way to verify user ID and their email. I store the token in the cookies. Now if the token is getting cracked like this then this jwt mechanism is basically meaningless right?

Comment: No, it's not.  You shouldn't store sensitive data in the JWT - just the users ID.  What makes the JWT secure is the fact that it is *signed*.  No one can create a fake JWT without your secret key - this stops people from "pretending" to be other people by creating their own JWTs.

Comment: **"issue is that it does get decoded on that site without any key"** - your token is not encrypted, hence jwt.io will show you the contents. The token itself is encoded in base64 which doesn't protect the content from being read. On jwt.io, you will see that there is a statement 'invalid signature'. Provide your secret key and you will see this changed to 'valid'. You are only protecting it using MAC - stops modification of the token. If you want to encrypt/decrypt, you can checkout my [libsodium container](https://github.com/Jaquarh/PHPEncrypter) to make it easy.

Comment: Hi Luke, and Jaquarah, I just tried to test you've said. Ive understood its not modifyable. 
I am not sending sensitive data in JWT anyway. So you were correct, I do not need encryption. 
However Ive one question what if I set JWT timer to 24 hours for e.g. and some other user uses the same token it would be an identity theft. How do I combat this?
Earlier I misunderstood JWT concept. Thank you so much for taking the time and clearing the concepts for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some concepts mixed up. JWT's, or better known as JSON Web Tokens, are built on the cryptology concept of [message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (MAC).

MAC gives the ability to confirm that the message came from the stated sender. It does not 'encrypt' the data thus you being able to see the direct contents of the message.

Base64 is a mutual translator for any datatype, JWT will use this encoding so you can put objects, arrays or whatever data you like inside of these tokens. Only, it ensures that no modification has been made to it.

For example, user A steals user B's JWT. He wants to access more data for more period of time so he tries to alter the exp property, he cannot resign the JWT with the MAC since he does not know the secret (in your case, the `$privateKey`).

When he then sends the new JWT to your server, it will throw a `InvalidSignatureError` which you can catch with your `try catch finally` blocks.

This can throw multiple errors, like expired token, so I'd suggest using `catch(Exception $e)` and then working with what type of error it was.

If you're looking to encrypt the contents (although it defeats the point of using JWT) you can use LibSodium, or a [container I made](https://github.com/Jaquarh/PHPEncrypter) for making it easier.

If you do not want to encrypt the `$token`, then do not put sensitive items inside of the token.

Comment: Hi Jaquarah, 
I just tried to test you've said. Ive understood its not modifyable. I am not sending sensitive data in JWT anyway. So you were correct, I do not need encryption. However Ive one question what if I set JWT timer to 24 hours for e.g. and some other user uses the same token it would be an identity theft. How do I combat this? Earlier I misunderstood JWT concept. Thank you so much for taking the time and clearing the concepts for me. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: tokens will always be unique because of the time stamp - there should never be a case of duplicate tokens. For example, if the resource bearer is requested twice, the same data is provided however the timestamp will be seconds out thus causing a complete new token. Hope this helps clarify your concerns @SP